# Is there a nextflow beautifier/formatter similar to black for Python?

Tags: groovy, code-formatting, nextflow

Is there a nextflow beautifier similar to [black](https://github.com/psf/black) but for nextflow?

I often have some long calls:

```
process_01(one_ch.first(), two.out.average_two.first(), three.out.file, four_ch, five_ch, six.out.files.flatten().collate(10))
```

That would profit quite a lot from an automatic formatter (on save) into the something [like](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/dsl2.html#pipes):

```
workflow {
channel.from('Hello') \
  | map { it.reverse() } \
  | (foo & bar) \
  | mix \
  | view
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid that the answer is no, not yet (that I'm aware of). There are a lot of people who would love to have one though! There are some current efforts ongoing - see the Nextflow / nf-core Slack channel [`#prettier-plugin-nextflow`](https://nextflow.slack.com/archives/C037JAEV9GS) and [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/nf-core/tools/issues/1642).

For reference, running Groovy code formatters sadly doesn't work well in my experience :(

Comment: "Groovy code formatters sadly doesn't work well" do you mean that it doesnt work at all? Or just gives bad results?

Comment: It's now been a couple of years since I last tried, so I'm not confident to say "not at all". There are many to choose from and nothing stands still. But when I last tried I ended up abandoning the effort and doing stuff manually instead. I am pretty sure it was breaking the code. Nextflow is custom DSL built on top of Groovy, so doesn't follow Groovy language syntax exactly.

Note that we are hoping to ship some Nextflow features somewhat along these lines in 2024, if all goes well.